# GAE Python - 'InboundEmailMessage' object has no attribute 'cc'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, attributeerror

I'm processing inbound email on GAE and have a problem detecting if there is a value for CC. The code basically has to do 3 things:
1) Do nothing if there is no value for CC.
2) Save the CC to item.cc when it is present.
3) If an error occurs, log it.
I've written following code to do this:

```
import traceback
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler

from myapp.models import Item

class MyTask(InboundMailHandler):
  def receive(self, mail_message):

    item = Item()

    try:
        if mail_message.cc == None:
            pass
        else:
            item.cc = mail_message.cc
    except:
        stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.error("%s", stacktrace)

    item.put()
```

However, when I process an email without a CC value, I get following error:

> AttributeError: 'InboundEmailMessage' object has no attribute 'cc'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the source, it looks like most of the attributes of an `InboundEmailMessage` only get set at all if they'd have a non-empty value.

You could do something like:

```
try:
    item.cc = mail_message.cc
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: I had something like that before, however I wasn't sure if it would then still also run my additional exception. In addition, I'm not sure if AttributeError couldn't contain other additional errors then just the fact that the attribute isn't there. Do you have any insight on this? Thanks!

Comment: That line of code is incredibly unlikely to raise any other exceptions that you'd need to report. In any event, uncaught exceptions should generally be getting logged by the App Engine runtime, so there's really no need to use a bare `except:` to catch stuff you can't handle and log it.

Comment: Is that because no mail server would allow incorrect data to be sent through?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the data is incorrect. You're just accessing an attribute and assigning it to a variable; whatever the data is, that shouldn't case an exception.

Comment: Alright thanks. Still it makes me wonder if I shouldn't be checking the CC value for anything, before I assign it to the variable.

Comment: Well, possibly. I *think* you can expect it to always be a non-empty string if it actually exists, although I haven't gone through the code all that carefully to check.